# Web application framework for an embedded device?

Tags: web-applications, embedded, wt

What is a suitable web application platform for an embedded system running a minimal version of Linux on an ARM spec'd at 200-400MHz with around 50-100MB RAM?

I could use simple CGI and some C/C++ code, but the designs I want to do are somewhat involved. Live updating, configuration management, logging, possibly streaming graphs and a small local SQL database.

I have looked into Wt, as I use Qt for many things, and it seems to do everything I want, but I have concerns about the cross compilation process. It seems overly complicated with the boost library requirements as well as CMake and very little all inclusive documentation on the procedure.  Is there a decent breakdown out there? The ones I have found are missing sections.

There seem to be plenty of options involving PHP and Java, but I just haven't had much experience with those languages as I don't typically do server side development.

Many of the others I have seen are not geared towards embedded systems, are there some other good options to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Wt performance is very good on such systems. There's some information on [cross compiling Wt for raspberry pi](http://redmine.emweb.be/projects/wt/wiki/Cross_compile_Wt_on_Raspberry_Pi) and [cross compiling Wt for Android](http://redmine.emweb.be/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_Android) on the Wt wiki. The exact process depends a lot on the cross compilation tools you use for your platform.

Comment: Unfortunately I will likely be running a much less featured version of Linux than what the raspberry pi uses, so I won't have access to a precompiled boost library.  I have attempted something similar to the android process for my device before for this and could not get the process straight for my device.  Between the jam files, cmake, and the cross compilation, I manage to screw up something whenever I attempt this. The process is currently overly involved and under documented.